# Which framework to use for iPhone game development?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, coronasdk

I want to build game similar to iPhone doodle jump. Can anyone tell me the best framework to use for its development which is faster and easier?

I am confused between cocos2D, Sparrow and Corona? Which ones is easier and best to use? Are there any other worth considering?

Comment: cocos2D is the best platform for game development because it is free.

Comment: Does it handle all Physics, collisions etc like Corona does ?

Comment: Please find the link http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9024/comparison-between-cocos2d-and-corona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I suggest is **Box2d**. I recently created a game on Pogo Jump and used **Box2d** for creating it.
**Box2d** is able to show real jumping and running effects which might seem unnatural in **Cocos2d**. Also the *collision detection* is quite easy in comparison to **Cocos2d** where you detect collision on coordinate basis which is somewhat complex. On the contrary, in **Box2d** you need to create *bodies* and detect collision using a simple class known as *ContactListener*.

If you'll start creating your game in **Box2d** and will *unit test* it regularly, you'll definitely realize the difference I am trying to highlight.

Comment: OK. Can I use the Cocos2DandBox2D project template that comes up with Cocos2D installation ? Or do I need to use it differently ?

Comment: Yes, go with the project template. Creating menu doesn't require Box2d until and unless you want something different to be displayed. So you can use Cocos2D there. Inside the game you need to import<Box2d.h> do rename your layer or scene as layer.m or scene.m to layer.mm and scene.mm.

Comment: @Nitish - how can you make enemies on the platforms like that on doodlejump?

Answer (score 2):

Cocos 2d.

Here is a start point for you as well: http://iplayful.com/tweejump/

That'll help you understand the process behind creating a game like Doodle Jump. (don't just copy that though, there's already enough TweeJump clones around! :p)